# How to get right click context menu on certain file types in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, file, contextmenu, add-in

I am trying to developing an AddIn for Visual Studio to get a right click context menu for javascript files and image files. I have managed to add my Addin to the right click of all project items

What I want to achieve is to get the Addin **ONLY** on javascript files and image files. Something like this (Note:- currently I am getting Addin on **ALL** file types)

Below is the code I have in the connect

```
 if (connectMode == ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_UISetup)
        {
            object[] contextGUIDS = new object[] { };
            Commands2 commands = (Commands2)_applicationObject.Commands;
            string toolsMenuName = "Tools";

            //Place the command on the tools menu.
            //Find the MenuBar command bar, which is the top-level command bar holding all the main menu items:
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBar menuBarCommandBar = ((Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars)["MenuBar"];

            //Find the Tools command bar on the MenuBar command bar:
            CommandBarControl toolsControl = menuBarCommandBar.Controls[toolsMenuName];
            CommandBarPopup toolsPopup = (CommandBarPopup)toolsControl;

            Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBar itemToolBar = ((Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars)["Item"];

            //This try/catch block can be duplicated if you wish to add multiple commands to be handled by your Add-in,
            //  just make sure you also update the QueryStatus/Exec method to include the new command names.
            try
            {
                //Add a command to the Commands collection:
                Command command = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "CrmAddin", "CrmAddin", "Executes the command for CrmAddin", true, 59, ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported + (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled, (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);

                //Add a control for the command to the tools menu:
                if ((command != null) && (toolsPopup != null))
                {
                    command.AddControl(toolsPopup.CommandBar, 1);
                }

                if ((command != null) && (itemToolBar != null))
                {
                    command.AddControl(itemToolBar, 1);
                }
            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {
                //If we are here, then the exception is probably because a command with that name
                //  already exists. If so there is no need to recreate the command and we can
                //  safely ignore the exception.
            }
```

I tried to filter out the file types in the QueryStatus method like this but it is of no help

```
  if (neededText == vsCommandStatusTextWanted.vsCommandStatusTextWantedNone)
        {
            if (commandName == "CrmAddin.Connect.CrmAddin")
            {
                bool supportedFileTypes = true;
                foreach (Project project in _applicationObject.Solution.Projects)
                {
                    foreach (ProjectItem projectItem in project.ProjectItems)
                    {
                        if (!projectItem.Name.EndsWith(".js"))
                        {
                            supportedFileTypes = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (supportedFileTypes)
                {
                    status = (vsCommandStatus)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
                }
                else
                {
                    status = (vsCommandStatus)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported;
                }

                return;
            }
        }
```

Please help if anyone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Just for info.
Was looking for a solution to similar problem, found this first, then after some searching I saw your question on MSDN (?)
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/c8f35f82-c694-4a6a-8c4a-a8404a4df11f

Which gave the answer :)